# how to know programmatically any file is encrypted or not ?- iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption

I have a sqlite file(it may be either encrypted or non-encrypted) in Document Directory in an already created app, now in updated version i have to check it for decryption, if file is found encrypted then we will use it after decryption but it found non-encrypted then we will use it simply.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to ["The SQLite Database File Format"](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html),
every SQLite file starts with the bytes "SQLite format 3", followed by a nul termination.

Assuming that the encryption scrambles all bytes of the file, you can read the first 16
bytes and check if they match the above string.

But a simpler method is to just open the file with `sqlite3_open()` or one of the 
related open calls. If that fails with the error code `SQLITE_CORRUPT`, you can assume
that the file was encrypted, so you decrypt it and open it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the encryption method is beforehand, you can try to find fingerprints of the method in order to detect if the file is encrypted or not. But there are encryption methods that are designed specifically to hide encryption into files that do not look encrypted.

This is the case of watermarking encryption embedded into images. You can open the images and they will look like any ordinary image file, but in fact there is encrypted information there.